# Chart.js update chart when legend label is hidden?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, data-visualization

Chart.js 3 -
I have a Doughnut chart that has a legend with a `generateLabels` function that changes the text color based on the graph color.

```
         plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              generateLabels: (chart) => {
                if (chart.data.labels.length && chart.data.datasets.length) {
                  return chart.data.labels.map((label, i) => ({
                    text: label,
                    fontColor: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
                    fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
                    strokeStyle: '#fff',
                    hidden: myChart ? myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[i].hidden : false
                  }));
                }
              },
            },
```

However, I need to chart to update like it used to with it's default behavior and collapse the data in the chart if the legend item is "hidden".  I'm able to do it manually, but it's with hard coded values:

```
            ...
            onClick: (event, legendItem) => {
              const metaData = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data;
              const iData = labs.indexOf(legendItem.text);
              metaData[iData].hidden ? myChart.datasets[0].data[iData] = 0 : 
                  myChart.data.datasets[0].data[iData] = 1;
              metaData[iData].hidden = !metaData[iData].hidden;
              myChart.update();
            },
```

How can I get the original behavior of the chart updating when the legend item has strikethrough and is "hidden"?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I hope this will also help other devs.

I also came across this issue, I found out that every time you try you click the legend, the callback of `generateLabels` also executes.

So you need to use the chart's existing `legendItems` after the first generation to avoid overriding properties.

```js
plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              generateLabels: (chart) => {
                if (chart.data.labels.length && chart.data.datasets.length) {
                  return chart.legend.legendItems ?? chart.data.labels.map((label, i) => ({
                    text: label,
                    fontColor: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
                    fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
                    strokeStyle: '#fff',
                    hidden: myChart ? myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[i].hidden : false
                  }));
                }
              },
            },
```